# Linq - Devolver el máximo valor de uno de los campos

Tags: c#, linq

Al hacer una consulta SQL tengo unos resultados tal que así:

```
Usuario Total
Javier   20
Javier   25
Javier   10
Alfredo  15
Alfredo  12
```

Necesito que el resultado sea el máximo Total de cada Usuario, es decir:

```
Usuario Total
Javier   25
Alfredo  15
```

Al hacerl usando .Max, selecciona solo el máximo del total y devuelve un registro:

```
var query = (from table 
            select new { Usuario, Total }).Max(x=> x.Total);
```

Necesitaría algo así:

```
var query = (from table 
            select new { Usuario, max(Total) }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

Puedes logralo utilizando `GroupBy()` utilizando el Usuario como Key:

```
var datos = (from t in table
group by t.Usuario into t2
select new { Nombre = t2.Key, Total = t2.Max() });
```

O tambien:

```
var datos = table.GroupBy(x=>x.Usuario)
                 .Select(x=> new { Nombre = x.Key, Total = x.Max() });
```